# How to Run a script at the start of Container in Cloud Containers Engine with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run a shell script at the start of a docker container running on Google Cloud Containers using Kubernetes. The structure of my app directory is something like this. I'd like to run prod_start.sh script at the start of the container (I don't want to put it as part of the Dockerfile though). The current setup fails to start the container with `Command not found file ./prod_start.sh does not exist`. Any idea how to fix this?

```
app/
  ...
  Dockerfile
  prod_start.sh
  web-controller.yaml
  Gemfile
  ...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby
RUN mkdir /backend
WORKDIR /backend
ADD Gemfile /backend/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /backend/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
```

web-controller.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    app: myapp
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: myapp
    tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        tier: backend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: secrets
        secret:
          secretName: secrets
      containers:
      - name: my-backend
        command: ['./prod_start.sh']
        image: gcr.io/myapp-id/myapp-backend:v1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets
          mountPath: /etc/secrets
          readOnly: true
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http-server
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just include it in the Docker image and not use it except for your production environment?

Comment: I guess I just don't want to complicate the shell script to check if I am in production or not and then based on that do the proper setting of the environment variables setting from kubernetes secrets. I use the same Dockerfile for development purposes as well where I have a `docker-compose.yaml` and it runs a `dev_start.sh`.

Comment: You could just have the prod_start.sh script in the image but run a different command when not in production couldn't you?

Comment: can you try using absolute path of your script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of experimentations I believe adding the script to the `Dockerfile`:

```
ADD prod_start.sh /backend/prod_start.sh
```

And then calling the command like this in the `yaml` controller file:

```
command: ['/bin/sh', './prod_start.sh']
```

Fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

you can add a config map to your yaml instead of adding to your dockerfile.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    app: myapp
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: myapp
    tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        tier: backend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: secrets
        secret:
          secretName: secrets
      - name: prod-start-config
        configMap:
          name: prod-start-config-script
          defaultMode: 0744
      containers:
      - name: my-backend
        command: ['./prod_start.sh']
        image: gcr.io/myapp-id/myapp-backend:v1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets
          mountPath: /etc/secrets
          readOnly: true
        - name: prod-start-config
          mountpath: /backend/
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http-server
```

Then create another yaml file for your script:
script.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: 
  name: prod-start-config-script
data:
  prod_start.sh: |
    apt-get update
```

When deployed the script will be in the scripts directory